# Experimental NDK Support on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have experience with Android development on Eclipse, but I'm quite new to this gradle stuff.

I created a project on Android Studio and tried adding native library support. I followed the documents on android.com

1. [Android NDK Preview](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview)
2. [Experimental Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)

I bumped into the following problem and I'm not even familiar with the terminology! It says: *Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl'*

[image: error description]

Suggestions did not solve the problem. How can I solve it?

Here are the contents of the `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle`:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.wofm"
            minSdkVersion = 15
            targetSdkVersion = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "wofmUtil"
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles = getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            proguardFiles += 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you try with the updated plugin 0.2.1 ?

Comment: By that, if you mean changing the classpath in build.gradle into `'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1'`, then yes. The error persists.

Answer (score 4):

You should use  `minSdkVersion.apiLevel` and `targetSdkVersion.apiLevel` instead of `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. And I also had a problem with `getDefaultProguardFile()` so I had to remove it.